# C# - Random Number Generator error

Tags: c#

When I run this and play the game, only the number 0 is being generated each time. Can you help me figure what the problem is?

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    int numberguessed;
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Random randnum = new Random();
        int numberguessed = randnum.Next(0,1000);
    }



    private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myTextBlock.Text = " No worries ! Go again .. ";
        myTextbox.Text = "";
        myTextbox.Focus();
    }

    private void myButton2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //string sval = myTextbox.Text;
        int ival = System.Convert.ToInt32(myTextbox.Text);
        if (ival == numberguessed)
            myTextBlock.Text = " You won ";
        else if (ival < numberguessed)
            myTextBlock.Text = "Your guess is too low !";
        else if (ival > numberguessed)
            myTextBlock.Text = "Your guess is too high !";
    }

    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myTextbox.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I suppose we keep each other honest then!

Answer (score 4):

in this part

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Random randnum = new Random();
        int numberguessed = randnum.Next(0,1000);
    }
```

You are overwritting your top level numberguessed variable by prefixing it with "int". Change it to:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Random randnum = new Random();
        numberguessed = randnum.Next(0,1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You declare `numberguessed` as a `field`, and then redeclare a new  local variable `int numberguessed` in `MainPage()`. In the other methods, the `field` value will be used. As it's not initialized, it will have the default value for an int, 0.

```
int numberguessed;
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Random randnum = new Random();
            //remove int there like this
            //int numberguessed = randnum.Next(0,1000);
           numberguessed = randnum.Next(0,1000);
        }
```

By the way you should have a warning (or maybe it's just resharper doing it) stating that

> Local variable numberguessed hides fields .MainPage.numberguessed

Answer (score 0):

change this part

```
int numberguessed;
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Random randnum = new Random();
        int numberguessed = randnum.Next(0,1000);
    }
```

To

```
 private int numberguessed;
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Random randnum = new Random();
        numberguessed = randnum.Next(0,1000);
    }
```

The problem is the fact that once you are declaring your field/property in the class and then creating a similar field with the declaration of `int numberguessed` again inside the constructor. This latter field only remains in scope inside the constructor and dies off once the constructor ends. However, the default value of all int fields are 0 and the field you are accessing is the one defined OUTSIDE the class. Hence you are getting only a default value.